# JPA + Datanucleus + Connection pooling : connections are opened/closed with each statement

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I am using JPA and data nucleus, in order to access a postgresql database.
My setup is as follows :

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="postgresql" >
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.something.DbClass1</class>
    <class>com.something.DbClass2</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://IP:5432/some_db"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionUserName" value="username"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionPassword" value="password"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.connectionPoolingType" value="C3P0"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have also defined the C3P0.properties file :

```
c3p0.minPoolSize=15
c3p0.maxPoolSize=100
c3p0.initialPoolSize=15
```

I am using EntityManager like this :

```
EntityManager em = entityManager();
DbClass1 x = em.merge(input);
em.close();
```

Now, I have some oddities in the debug log. Connections seem to get opened/closed with each query (please see below):
Is anybody able to point out what I'm doing wrong here ? Thanks !

```
13:13:43,969 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Adding support for Java type boolean (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
13:13:43,970 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Adding support for Java type byte (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
13:13:43,970 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Adding support for Java type char (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
...
13:13:44,738 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry] - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
13:13:44,766 DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean] - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[1br5qth8q1lseuas1a25ohv|38d0357a] registered.
13:13:44,781 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Created tx data source using pooling type of C3P0
13:13:44,781 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Registered transactional connection factory under name "rdbms/tx"
13:13:44,796 DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean] - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[1br5qth8q1lseuas1a25ohv|2415a94f] registered.
13:13:44,796 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Created nontx data source using pooling type of C3P0
13:13:44,796 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Registered nontransactional connection factory under name "rdbms/nontx"
13:13:44,915 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource] - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1br5qth8q1lseuas1a25ohv|2415a94f, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1br5qth8q1lseuas1a25ohv|2415a94f, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 15, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://IP:5432/some_db, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 3600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 100, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 15, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
13:13:45,201 DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@2a801059.acquireResource() returning. 
13:13:45,203 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@695cd9c0" opened
13:13:45,205 DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@2a801059.acquireResource() returning. 
13:13:45,205 DEBUG [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@2a801059.acquireResource() returning. 
13:13:45,308 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Adding RDBMS support for Java type java.lang.Boolean (jdbc-type=BIT, sql-type=BIT, datastore-mapping-type=org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.BitRDBMSMapping, default=true)
13:13:45,309 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Adding RDBMS support for Java type java.lang.Boolean (jdbc-type=CHAR, sql-type=CHAR, datastore-mapping-type=org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.CharRDBMSMapping, default=false)
13:13:45,310 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Adding RDBMS support for Java type java.lang.Boolean (jdbc-type=BOOLEAN, sql-type=BOOLEAN, datastore-mapping-type=org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.BooleanRDBMSMapping, default=false)
13:13:45,311 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Adding RDBMS support for Java type java.lang.Boolean (jdbc-type=SMALLINT, sql-type=SMALLINT, datastore-mapping-type=org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.SmallIntRDBMSMapping, default=false)
...
13:14:11,791 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object "<redacted>@52c51614" being inserted into table "<redacted>""
13:14:11,791 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection added to the pool : [org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@1b78efd8, null] for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@699c9f16 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl@29422384]
13:14:11,791 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Setting autocommit=false to connection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@455dd32a
13:14:11,842 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@455dd32a" opened with isolation level "read-committed"
13:14:11,843 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist] - Retrieving PreparedStatement for connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@455dd32a"
13:14:11,843 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - INSERT INTO <redacted> ...
13:14:11,843 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - INSERT INTO <redacted> ...
13:14:11,897 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist] - Execution Time = 53 ms (number of rows = 1)
13:14:11,897 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Insert of object "<redacted>" is calling insertPostProcessing for field "<redacted>"
13:14:11,897 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Retrieve] - Closing PreparedStatement org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@3970ae0
13:14:11,990 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@455dd32a" non enlisted to a transaction is being committed.
13:14:11,990 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@455dd32a" closed
13:14:11,990 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection removed from the pool : [org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@1b78efd8, com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@455dd32a] for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@699c9f16 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl@29422384]
```

Comment: I think that's a good thing.  It's far more scalable.  The pool is handling all this, as it should.  I see nothing wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is a misunderstanding on my side. The whole purpose of a connection pool is to keep the connection opened for a period of time, in order to avoid re-opening a new connection with each operation (i.e. (1) open connection, (2) run query1, (3) run query2, (4) close connection, AS OPPOSED TO (1) open connection, (2) run query1, (3) close connection, (4) open connection, (5) run query2, (6) close connection). Am I missing something here ?

Comment: No, connection pools do not keep the connection open for a period of time.  They amortize the code of opening a connection across multiple connections.  I could be wrong, but I think you are missing something.    Your scenarios depend on the way you use the pool, not the pool itself.

Comment: really ?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: Don't care about Wikipedia.  I typically write a method that checks a connection out of the pool, uses it to execute multiple SQL statements as a single unit of work, commits or rolls back the work (all or none), then returns the connection to the pool.  It's under the control of you and your code.  This is the way it's done.  Read up on transaction managers, units of work, and ACID for relational databases.

Comment: ok, maybe I'm wrong here. Can you point me to 1 single tech article that mentions that connection pools DO NOT keep the connection open ? I honestly believe that's their main purpose.

Comment: by the way - I agree with you, but that is why we have transactions for - to group everything under a single unit of work. Connections are relatively expensive to open/close.

Comment: That's what the pool is managing for you.  I don't have a reference, but I know that it can't be the way you're assuming.  If it was as you said, there's no way to do multiple statements in a single transaction.  It can't work as you describe with the connection closing after every statement.  The transaction is associated with the connection.  That's why the service layer manages the connection and gives it to the DAOs to use on the unit of work.  You'll have to give up this cherished belief.  Try it with JPA - it supports JTA.  Prove it to yourself.

Comment: Let's clarify a bit. I'm saying that (1) connection pools, as a general concept, keep the connection behind opened for a period of time, and that's their main purpose and (2) yes, I agree that in my scenario something is wrong, either in config, either in my code.

So you are saying that it's ok that connection closes after every statement, or after every group of statements (I haven't checked if I execute sequentially multiple statements what happens), and yet, you don't have a reference regarding (1), for something as general as a connection pool ??

Comment: another one for example : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pool/

Comment: You control the pool, not the other way 'round.  You check it out; you check it in.  What's done in between is up to you and your code.  If you've written your example so it's just a bunch of queries, each with their own connection, then you'll get the behavior you observed.  Sorry, I'm done with this conversation.  No one else has been interested enough to answer.  Let's see if they do.  If not, you're on your own.  Good luck.

Comment: duffymo did you consider changing your name to pissymo? :-P. I'm not familiar with data nucleus but I believe that Andrei have a point. The main purpose of a connection pool is to reuse connections. because creation is expensive.

Comment: He's the type of person that rarely admits he's wrong. Apart from that, he's not the first, otherwise experienced person, to have this misconception. Strangely, I have seen it in several places.

Comment: I think perhaps duffymo was saying that with a pool, the connections obtained from the pool can be opened and closed at will, because the underlying connection is not being opened and closed each time. This does seem to align with @DataNucleus's interpretation of this log, FWIW.

Comment: This could be right. I have checked by running a query with a separate client, against the DB server, and indeed, I was seeing connections opened, about the size of connection pool, although the log kept telling me "connection closed".

Comment: @Tom Anderson, I said in my answer that DN will get a connection and call close on it when no longer needed. This is the C3P0 connection, not the real connection. C3P0 manages the real connection, which it can obviously open/close as it sees fit ... the job of a pool. That aligns EXACTLY with the statement you made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean that you have a DataSource (for C3P0) and that DataNucleus gets a connection, and calls close on it when it doesn´t need it. And indeed this is exactly what you are supposed to do for a connection pool DataSource. And C3P0 controls when the real JDBC connection is actually closed. So no, DataNucleus is doing nothing wrong there as far as i can see (in the publically viewable code).

You refer to some nontransactional code (so the connection will only be held for a single operation, unless you have a persistence property set to retain it, in the docs), and refer to a "query" yet I see no such query, just a "merge".

Comment: You are right. The "real" connection does not get closed. I have checked meanwhile with a query against the server, and I see connections as IDLE, about the size of the connection pool. 
P.S. "merge" ultimately results in a query, in my code. Even with non-transactional code, the connection pool should still get used.

Comment: you can configure c3p0 internal behaviour of course, like max no of idle connections.

Comment: I know. Thanks for the help. It doesn't bother me they are IDLE. Just mentioned it by accident.